# Voltage Dividers in a pull-up resistor circuit (why does the pin go to low)

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, pullup

[image: pullup]

I understand that when the button is in its open state the voltage on the input pin should be fairly close to \$ V_{cc} \$ provided \$ R_1 << R_2 \$ as \$ V_{in} = V_{cc} \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}\$. But, I do not understand why the voltage on the input pin changes to low (close to 0) when the button is closed.

Comment: The switch shorts the input pin directly to ground, i.e. 0V.

Comment: @JohnD Please don't put answers in the comment section.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement I answered in the comments under the following scenario for answering in comments which is a well-accepted answer on the meta site for this StackExchange:  The question is a good one and deserves a complete answer, but I only have time to give a brief answer. I want to leave the answer space open so somebody else can write the complete answer and get the rep for it.

Comment: @JohnD On your authority, and noting your not insignificant reputation around here, I retract my correction. Godspeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press the button, you connect the input pin, and the bottom end of R1, to ground.

Current will flow through R1, and through the button to ground.

Comment: So, because the pin is now directly connected to ground it has a \$0V\$ relative to ground. But will any current flow through the pin? Isn't it now basically the same as a parallel circuit?

Comment: Whether any current flows into or out of the pin depends on the actual internal circuit of the MCU.  In most CMOS ICs, the input is the insulated gate of a MOSFET transistor - this has nearly infinite resistance, so no current will flow.  However, many microcontrollers have internal pull-up (or, less often, pull-down) resistors on their inputs which can be enabled or disabled under program control - if a pull-up is enabled, it will effectively be in parallel with R1, and current will flow out of theinput pin, to ground.

Answer (score 1):

The question is written from the voltage divider perspective.  So, let's roll with the voltage divider perspective a little further.  Imagine that the switch is a resistance, which varies when switch is opened of closed.

Open switch has an infinite resistance: \$ R_{sw,open} >> R_2 \$

Closed switch has a very low resistance (essentially, it's a short circuit): \$ R_{sw,closed} << R_2 \$

In either case, very little current flows through the microntroller pin, because it has high input impedance (resistance).  \$ R_2 \$ doesn't change depending on the state on the switch.

**p.s.**  I would designate it \$ R_{in} \$ instead of \$ R_2 \$, because it's an input impedance.